# SSL error between jenkins(java) and Bitbucket Plugin

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, bitbucket

I`m using CentOS 6.5 in AWS.

java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.6.4.el6_8-x86_64 u101-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Using Jenkins 2.15(new installation) and last version of [Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin)

I start Branch Indexing with my login data for Bitbucket but get these errors:

```
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using ****/******
Looking up ****/****for branches
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of ***** » **** » build
com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.api.BitbucketRequestException: Communication error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudApiClient.getRequest(BitbucketCloudApiClient.java:421)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudApiClient.getBranches(BitbucketCloudApiClient.java:217)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieveBranches(BitbucketSCMSource.java:323)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieve(BitbucketSCMSource.java:279)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:146)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:294)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:157)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:122)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1874)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1857)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1783)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudApiClient.getRequest(BitbucketCloudApiClient.java:412)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:146)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:704)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:78)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:717)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:721)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:126)
    ... 29 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I will be glad for advice.

Comment: I have the same error but on windows, normal HTTPS works fine as i added the certs to the Store, did you get anywhere with this ?

Comment: See my answer in the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this directory:

```
/lib/security
```

of my Java installation, I found a `java.security` file.

I commented this line:

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768
```

and this:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

And Jenkins and Bitbucket plugin is working.